# Extracting a particular string from a complex string in Powershell

Tags: powershell, extract, substring

I have a string like the below which I read from a file.

```
...

{File}
Filecopied;Source;Destination;Archived;
feed_ma_expected_close_date.sql;C:\Users\subiswal\Desktop\Minor_DataEntry\Source\feed\;C:\Users\subiswal\Desktop\Minor_DataEntry\Destination1\feed\;C:\Users\subiswal\Desktop\Minor_Data    Entry\Destination1\Backup\2013-04-03-12-12-58_Backup\feed\;
{\File}

{File}
Filecopied;Source;Destination;Archived;
feed_ma_expected_close_date.csv;C:\Users\subiswal\Desktop\Minor_DataEntry\Source\feed\;C:\Users\subiswal\Desktop\Minor_DataEntry\Destination1\feed\;C:\Users\subiswal\Desktop\Minor_DataEntry\Destination1\Backup\2013-04-03-12-12-58_Backup\feed\;
{\File}

...
```

I need to find all the text between `{File}` and `{\File}` and all those strings I need to store in a String Array.

Comment: And you're try is where? This isn't a webshop for scripts, it's a community, so at least give it a try yourself. Btw, what is "all those strings"? You want to extract the csv parts of it? Should the header only be kept once? or are there different headers thoughout the file?

Comment: So what have you tried? And what exactly is the question? Remember, this is not a "do it for me" site.

Comment: Sorry, I am a novice in powershell, and using the community for the first time. My objective was to extract all strings from the text file, which has a pattern {File} **** {\File}. May be its an obvious doubts, but any help is most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do is to:

1. Read the file. Look up `Get-Content`.
2. Loop through the file contents and look for desired data. The trivial way is to use a for loop. Multiline regexp might work too.
3. When match, extract data.
4. Save the data. Look up `Set-Content` and `Add-Content`.